# as3 removeChild - I cannot target specific children

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm still trying to get my head around AS3 and can't figure out how to target some specific Children in my project and remove them... I'm sure there's a simple solution to this on page 1 of a "Basic AS3" book somewhere but I can't work it out!

I'm trying to remove the red lines created in the addNewPoint function (or just give them an alpha of 0) as part of the fillDriveway function.

I can give you a link to the source files if you need.

Thanks so so much in advance!

Here's my terrible code:

```
    import flash.display.*

pic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,addNewPoint);

var n:Number = 0;

function addNewPoint(e:MouseEvent):void {
    n++;
    pointNo.text = String(n);
    var nextPoint:MovieClip = new newPoint();
    addChild(nextPoint);
    nextPoint.name = "mc"+pointNo.text;
    nextPoint.x = e.target.mouseX;
    nextPoint.y = e.target.mouseY;

    var joinPoints:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    this.addChild(joinPoints);
    joinPoints.graphics.lineStyle(0.5,0xFF0000);
    joinPoints.graphics.moveTo(this.getChildByName("mc1").x, this.getChildByName("mc1").y);
    for(var i:int=2; i<=n; ++i){
        joinPoints.graphics.lineTo(this.getChildByName("mc"+i).x, this.getChildByName("mc"+i).y);
    }
}

pic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addNewPoint);

function fillDriveway(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
    var joinPoints:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    this.addChild(joinPoints);
    joinPoints.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0.7);
    joinPoints.graphics.moveTo(this.getChildByName("mc1").x, this.getChildByName("mc1").y);
    for(var m:int=2; m<=n; ++m){
        joinPoints.graphics.lineTo(this.getChildByName("mc"+m).x, this.getChildByName("mc"+m).y);
    }
    joinPoints.name = "driveshape";
    filledDrive.text = "filled";
}

function undoit(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
    if(n > 0) {
        if(filledDrive.text.indexOf("filled") != -1) {
            this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(this.numChildren -1));
            filledDrive.text = "";
            }else{
            this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(this.numChildren -1));
            this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(this.numChildren -1));
            n--;
            pointNo.text = String(n);
        }
    }
}

undo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, undoit);

function maskDrive(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
    if(filledDrive.text.indexOf("filled") != -1) {
        var finishA:MovieClip = new finishMC();
        this.addChild(finishA);
        finishA.x = 310;
        finishA.y = 100;
        finishA.mask = getChildByName("driveshape");
        finishA.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}

//BTN Actions
function btn1over(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn1.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function btn1out(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn1.gotoAndPlay(11);
}
function btn2over(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn2.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function btn2out(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn2.gotoAndPlay(11);
}
function btn3over(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn3.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function btn3out(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn3.gotoAndPlay(11);
}

//BTN Calls
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fillDriveway);
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn1over);
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn1out);
btn1.buttonMode = true;
btn1.useHandCursor = true;
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, maskDrive);
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn2over);
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn2out);
btn2.buttonMode = true;
btn2.useHandCursor = true;
btn3.buttonMode = true;
btn3.useHandCursor = true;
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn3over);
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn3out);
```

Comment: What do you want to do and what happens? Your code is quite long, it requires some energy to understand it :)

Comment: Yes it is quite long sorry! The addNewPoint function adds an mc where user clicks, then every subsequent click it adds another mc at that point and joins from the previous point to the new point with a red line. Then the fillDriveway function fills this shape drawn in so that I can use it to mask an image. But when fillDriveway is called I would like it to first delete all of the red lines drawn (not the mcs at those points though)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that each time you create a new joinPoints you are overwriting the pointer to the previous joinPoints instance, therefore you cannot access it. (this will create a memory leak).

Each time you create a joinPoints object, add it to an array:

```
joinPointsArray.push(joinPoints);
```

Your fillDriveway function can then access all the joinPoints you have created:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < joinPointsArray.length, i++) {
joinPointsArray[i].alpha = 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice one thanks crooksy88 - I have another question relating to this project so I will pop it on now... Owe you one!